# How to show Scrollview images horizontally having 2 columns

Tags: react-native

**Hii i want to display images horizontally having 2 columns for this i am using scrollview but i dont know how to do that , i am using following code**

**code to fetch api**

```
 componentDidMount(){
return fetch('https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ccLAsEcOSq?indent=1')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: responseJson.book_array,
    }, function(){
    });
  })
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.error(error);
  });
```

}

**code for render**

```
render() {
if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
  return <ActivityIndicator color={'red'} />;
}
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
      {this.state.dataSource.map(item => this.renderItem(item))}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```

}
}

**code for renderItem**

```
renderItem(item) {
return (
  <View style={{ margin: 5 }}>
    <View style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        marginBottom: 1,
      }}>
       <Image  style={{ width: 150,height: 150}}
                      source={{uri: item.image}}/>  
    </View> 

    <View style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        marginBottom: 1,
      }}>
       <Image  style={{ width: 150,height: 150}}
                      source={{uri: item.image}}/>  
    </View> 

  </View>
);}
```

Comment: Before rendering the view, you need to divide your original array into even and odd array,by adding even/odd check. Then just render those array using Flatlist or using map function or whatever suitable component you want.

Comment: I know but i dont know how to do this..

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `ScrollView` try `FlatList` which provides `numColumns` props which lets you allow to use columns as per your choice.

Instead of this,

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
      {this.state.dataSource.map(item => this.renderItem(item))}
</ScrollView>
```

Use this,

```
<FlatList 
   data={this.state.dataSource}
   numColumns={2}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>
```

For more details of `FlatList` see [Official Docs Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

Comment: hii i want to scroll images horizontally having two columns  upper row contain even images and lower row contain odd images

Answer (score 1):

Try flex-direction property:

```
renderItem(item) {
return (
 <View style={{ margin: 5, flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around" }} >
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "red", width: 150, height: 150, marginBottom: 1 }} >
      <Image style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
    </View>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "red", width: 150, height: 150, marginBottom: 1 }} >
      <Image style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
    </View>
  </View>
);}
```

Comment: hii i want to scroll images horizontally having two columns  upper row contain even images and lower row contain odd images

Answer (score 1):

Use flat list inside scroll view like this

```
<FlatList
    horizontal={true}
    data={this.state.dataSource}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (this.renderItem({item}))}
    />
```

rearrange dataSource like this

```
array1 = [obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5,obj6,obj7,
array2=[[obj1,obj2],[obj3,obj4],[obj5,obj6],[obj7,obj8]]
```

and then render item with 2 rows.

didn't find any other way

Comment: hii i want to scroll images horizontally having two columns  upper row contain even images and lower row contain odd images

Comment: both      numColumns={2} , horizontal={true} cannot use simultaneously , im getting error

Comment: sorry didn't find any direct solution, but you can copy your array to a new one with each element having 2 objects , i will update the answer soon

Answer (score 1):

modify your ScrollView component Like this:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} contentContainerStyle={{height:300, flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
{this.state.dataSource.map(item => this.renderItem(item))}
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create view as you required need to implement your custom logic. In `render` function call a intermediate function to get columns in two row:

```
render() {
if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
  return <ActivityIndicator color={'red'} />;
}
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
        {this.renderHorizantol(this.state.dataSource)}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```

In `renderHorizantol` function need to set up logic for even or odd rows, i am implementing this on index of `dataSource` `Array`:

```
renderHorizantol = (dataSource) =>{
    let view = []
    for(let i=0 ; i < data.length ; i = i+2)
    {
        let subView = this.renderItem(dataSource[i],dataSource[i+1])
        view.push(subView)            
    }           
    return view 
}
```

In `renderItem` function pass two element to draw upper and lower row contents:

```
renderItem(item1,item2) {
    let image1 = item1["imageUrl"]
    let image2 = item2 ? item2["imageUrl"] : null
    return (
        <View style={{ margin: 5 }}>
        <View style={{
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            marginBottom: 1,
            }}>
            <Image  style={{ width: 150,height: 150}}
                            source={{uri: image1}}/>  
        </View> 

        <View style={{
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            marginBottom: 1,
            }}>
            <Image  style={{ width: 150,height: 150}}
                            source={{uri: image2}}/>  
        </View>     
    </View>
);}
```

Comment: @Hector4888 accept the answer if works for you, it helps others too in choosing correct answer.